# Setting background color of a form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

```
Private Sub HScrollBar1_Scroll(ByVal sender As Object, _
                               ByVal e As ScrollEventArgs) _
                               Handles HScrollBar1.Scroll
  Me.BackColor = HScrollBar1.Value
End Sub
```

How can I set the `BackColor` of the form? How can I use an RGB value?

Comment: I deleted the original, since it had no answers.  In the future, please just edit your question to bring it back to the front page instead of creating a duplicate.  Adding more details about what you're trying to do usually works wonders for getting new answers.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255,255,255)
```

...replacing the 255 on each parameter with the value you need. e.g.

```
Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(HScrollBar1.Value,HScrollBar2.Value,HScrollBar3.Value)
```

Comment: in which event we have to use this code? whether scroll event in scroll bar or in form load event? we tried in both scroll and load events.

Comment: You should use it in the scroll event if you want it to respond to each change.

Comment: Private Sub HScrollBar1_Scroll(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
 ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventArgs)Handles  HScrollBar1.Scroll

Me.BackColor Color.FromArgb(HScrollBar1.Value,HScrollBar2.Value,HScrollBar3.Value)


End sub



I used like this. The form background color is black, but the color didn't change as i scroll in the scroll bar.

Comment: The parameters have to be in the range 0-255.  Ensure your HScrollBar1.value is in that range, otherwise you may need to do some math.

Comment: I've set the parameters in range of 0-255 only. But in doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Color.FromArgb()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromargb.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [BackColor property documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor.aspx), use [System.Drawing.Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `formname.backcolor` to set the background color of a form programatically. For example:

```
formname.backcolor = vbred
```

For a red form background color.