# Changing the pixel color in a VB.net form?

Tags: vb.net, colors, pixel

How would I change the colour of individual pixels in a  VB.NET form?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please be more clear here? Why would you want to change individual pixels ?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/140505)

Comment: I'm making a program that displays the Mandelbrot Set, and I need to change the color of individual pixels on the form, as each pixel represents a point on the graph, and thus has it's own color.

Comment: Wow, stop being so aggressive. I've Googled as much as I can, the majority of the results lead to help with detecting individual pixel colors, and the few I have found about setting them just cause syntax errors. I know it's not a particularly advanced programming question, but I was just hoping someone could at least point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hard requirement for Winforms is that you should be able to redraw the form whenever Windows asks it to.  Which will happen when you minimize and restore the window.  Or on older versions of Windows when you move another window across yours.

So just setting pixels on the window isn't good enough, you are going to lose them all when the window redraws.  Instead use a bitmap.  An additional burden is that you are going to have to keep the user interface responsive so you need to do your calculations on a worker thread.  The BackgroundWorker is handy to get that right.

One way to do this is to use two bitmaps, one you fill in the worker and another that you display.  Every, say, one row of pixels make a copy of the in-work bitmap and pass that to ReportProgress().  Your ProgressChanged event then disposes the old bitmap and stores the new passed one and calls Invalidate to force a repaint.

Answer (score 0):

You might benefit from these resources: [Setting background color of a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248612/vb-net-setting-background-color-of-a-form)

[DeveloperFusion forum](http://www.developerfusion.com/thread/23944/how-do-i-find-the-color-of-a-pixel-in-vbnet/) , and [extracting pixel color](http://vbcity.com/forums/t/47691.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but what I really need is to change the color of pixels, not get the color of them. The only solution I know of would be to create a picture box for every pixel on the screen, and change the color of them, but that strikes me as being really inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some demo code. It's slow to repaint, for the reasons Hans mentioned. A simple way to speed it up would be to only recalculate the bitmap after a delay.

```
Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    'create new bitmap

    If Me.ClientRectangle.Width <= 0 Then Exit Sub
    If Me.ClientRectangle.Height <= 0 Then Exit Sub

    Using bmpNew As New Bitmap(Me.ClientRectangle.Width, Me.ClientRectangle.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
      'draw some coloured pixels
      Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpNew)
        For x As Integer = 0 To bmpNew.Width - 1
          For y As Integer = 0 To bmpNew.Height - 1
            Dim intR As Integer = CInt(255 * (x / (bmpNew.Width - 1)))
            Dim intG As Integer = CInt(255 * (y / (bmpNew.Height - 1)))
            Dim intB As Integer = CInt(255 * ((x + y) / (bmpNew.Width + bmpNew.Height - 2)))
            Using penNew As New Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, intR, intG, intB))
              'NOTE: when the form resizes, only the new section is painted, according to e.ClipRectangle.
              g.DrawRectangle(penNew, New Rectangle(New Point(x, y), New Size(1, 1)))
            End Using
          Next y
        Next x
      End Using
      e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmpNew, New Point(0, 0))
    End Using

  End Sub

  Private Sub Form1_ResizeEnd(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.ResizeEnd
    Me.Invalidate() 'NOTE: when form resizes, only the new section is painted, according to e.ClipRectangle in Form1_Paint(). We invalidate the whole form here to form an  entire form repaint, since we are calculating the colour of the pixel from the size of the form. Try commenting out this line to see the difference.
  End Sub

End Class
```